STATUS_REPORT provides the details memoryInfo": { "totalRam": "xxxxxxxxxx", "totalInternalStorage": "xxxxxxxxxx" } but it's differs from actual
STATUS_REPORT provides the details

memoryInfo": { "totalRam": "xxxxxxxxxx", "totalInternalStorage":
"xxxxxxxxxx" }

but it's differs from actual. Anyone facing issues?
We have tried to get the MEMORY, RAM and INTERNAL and EXTERNAL storage details from STATUS_REPORT of the enrolled devices. But it's sizes and measurements are varied from the actual size and measurements. Could any one facing the issues?

The memoryInfo measurements are taken asynchronously on the device either when a change is detected or when there is a periodic refresh of the device status. Whenever you call devices.get(), you can retrieve the last information sent from the device to the Android Management API servers. In addition, the memoryInfo's total Internal Storage is the measurement of the root of the total "system" partition storage. MemoryEvent returns 3 values per event: eventType, createTime, and byteCount.
